# Can a NAS HDD bottleneck a CPU when many cores access simultaneously to retrieve small files for processing?

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, nas

I got a Ryzen 3800X, a CPU with 8 high-performant cores. I also have a NAS with 5400 rpm HDDs that stores many thousands of small image files, ranging from 300KB to 700KB for processing by my OpenCV application running on the 3800X. However, based on Crystal Diskmark, most HDDs got peaked 4k read/write at 1 MB/s.

If the 8 CPU cores, or 16 CPU threads, continuously read from the HDD, would the time waiting to read files reduce the performance of my CPU, since if two or three files are read, then the other cores must wait?

Or suppose 16 CPU threads access the HDD at once, only the first 16 reads/seeks are random and then upon reading files, all becomes sequential reads?

Even so, my CPU can process 44 Mpixels/s at the minimum according to Geekbench JPEG compression/decompression benchmark. Assume a pixel is 4 bytes for each BGRA pixel, then 44 Mpixels = 44000000 (pixels) * 4 / (1024 * 1024) = 167 MB/s for a single core, way above even the sequential read from disk.

If so, should I see a substantial performance gained by putting in a SATA SSD?

Comment: HDDs were never good when used by more than one thread/process simultaneously, especially the slow 5400rpm one.

Comment: Also note that the network card can generally handle one command at a time, so it may limit your threading as well. I am pretty sure your bottleneck is IO, but keep in mind that from your threads perspective its just IO, but you actually have an entire remote system sitting in the middle of that transaction, so its harder to track down.